# Altering permission and roles tables spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

I am trying to implement this type of management in my application. Since I haven't done anything like that before this is the guide I followed: https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/user-roles-permissions-in-laravel/

And it worked like a charm!

What I wanted to do is change the migrations to alter the tables (they are made to work instantly in every project) The new tables follow the same logic but the problem comes from the `model_type` column in the `model_has_permissions` table. I removed this column and changed the `model_id` to refer to my `user_id` to make it look simpler. But in every query the application makes it adds the `model_has_permissions.model_type` which resolves an error.
I wonder have any of you guys have done this implementation before and do you have any ideas on what to edit to remove this column from the queries?

Any and all help greatly accepted!

Answer (score 0):

you will Override the Models
Create your own versions of the `Permission` and `Role` models provided by the package. In these models, you can override the relationships and methods that reference the old structure. Specifically, you'll want to update the `users`, `roles`, and permissions relationships to use your modified tables.

```
// CustomPermission.php
namespace App\Models;

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission as BasePermission;

class CustomPermission extends BasePermission
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'custom_model_has_permissions', 'model_id', 'permission_id');
    }
}

// CustomRole.php
namespace App\Models;

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as BaseRole;

class CustomRole extends BaseRole
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'custom_model_has_roles', 'model_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

Customize the Package's Service Provider 
 In your Laravel application's service providers, you can bind your custom models to the package's interfaces. This way, when the package accesses the models through its interfaces, it will use your custom models with the updated relationships.